# Definition of Cyclic subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> [image]

The above is a theorem from my book. What I don't understand is the second sentence when it says $b$ generates $H$ with $n/d$ elements. I thought that since $b = a^s$ generates $H$, it would have $s$ elements, meaning $H = \{e, a, a^2, \dots, a^s \}$? I've found some counterexamples to convince myself I am wrong, but I don't understand why my original idea is wrong either.

Comment: Why did you write $H = \{e, a, a^2, \ldots, a^s\}$? This is not what "generate" means. You should instead write $H = \{e, a^s, (a^s)^{-1}, (a^s)^2, (a^s)^{-2}, \ldots \}$ where the list goes on indefinitely. Of course, in your case $H$ will turn out finite because the list will eventually start repeating itself.

Comment: @DanShved, the inverse of $a$ would be $a^{s}$ and $a^{s-1}$ would be the inverse of $a^2$ and so on.

Comment: Why would the inverse of $a$ be $a^s$? There's no reason for that

Answer (score 1):

It means that the set $\{b^n : n\in\mathbb{Z}\} = \{a^{sn} : n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ *is* a cyclic subgroup of $G$ containing $n/d$ elements.

Comment: Maybe my question was ill-posed from the beginning. But I was under the impression that if an element $a$ generates a group and has order $s$, then it means the group contains $s$ elements.

Comment: $a^s$ doesn't have order $s$. Your looking at the group generated by $b = a^s$. For example, if $G$ is the cyclic group on 10 elements, and $a$ a generator of the group, and $s = 2$, then $a^s =a^2$ has order 5, because $(a^2)^5 = a^{10} = 1$

Answer (score 1):

$ x = o(a^s) = \frac{n}{\gcd(n,s)} $ .

Infact by definition $(a^s)^x = a^{sx} = 1$ . Then $$n \mid sx \Rightarrow \frac{n}{\gcd(n,s)} \mid x$$ Suppose $s = \gcd(n,s) \cdot k$ , then $$s \cdot \frac{n}{\gcd(n,s)} = \gcd(n,s) \cdot k  \cdot \frac{n}{\gcd(n,s)} = kn$$ and so $$(a^s) ^{\frac{n}{\gcd(n,s)}} = a^{kn} = (a^n)^k = 1$$ This implies $$x \mid \frac{n}{\gcd(n,s)}$$ and so $$x = \frac{n}{\gcd(n,s)}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Another proof**

Let $k=o\langle b\rangle=o\langle a^s\rangle$ be the order of `H`

and according to the definition,
$$a^n=e$$
and
$$b^k=(a^s)^k=a^{ks}=e$$
so that
$$n\mid ks$$
where k is the minimum possible value
$$ks\equiv 0 \pmod n$$
and finally
$$k=\frac{n}{\text{gcd}(n,s)}=n/d$$